# Passing Data from post() to get_context_data()

Tags: python, django

I am generating an object from a submitted form. I want to pass along the generated `AutoField` to the next form as a hidden form element. However, I cannot figure out how to pass a variable from `post()` to `get_context_data()`. I know that `post()` is called first, followed by `get_context_data()`, but adding the variable to `self` does not yield the results I expect (the attribute does not exist on `self`).

Here is an example of what I am experiencing:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    print self.hello
    return context

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.hello = "hello"
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
```

`self.hello` is not valid when called in `get_context_data`. I feel as though I may be mistaken with the `HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)` call, but I'm not sure how else to render the template.

Is it a simple mistake, or should I be approaching this an entirely different way?

Comment: `get_context_data()` is only run for `GET` requests (assuming you are using a `FormView`), and not for `POST` requests handled by `post()`. `get_context_data()` is used to get the template context, which is redundant if you're just redirecting anyway. Can you explain exactly what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm creating a single object across multiple forms. Form1 posts to Form2's page. I create half of the object in Form2's `post()` and would like to be able to submit Form2 to a landing page where the object is finalized. I need to know which object is being created, so I thought that I would grab the `AutoField` generated in the first `post()` and pass it as a hidden field in Form2 so the update on the landing page `post()` will access the correct object. I'm sure there's a better way, and I'm open to suggestions. (Other than FormWizard. This is an alternative to that for reasons...)

Comment: You could use sessions to store this data between views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find a way to pass the object ID to the next page. The options that come to mind are to put it into the URL or as solarissmoke has suggested save it in the session. If you are doing it in the url you can also put the page sequence there (meaning 1 for the forst form, 2 for the second...).

The nice thing about this approach is, that you can cover all functonailty in one view: depending on the page set the respective fields in the get_object methods (self.fields=[....]) and the template names in the get_template_names method.

So using an Updateview, it would look like this:

urls.py:

```
....
url(r'^mysite/(?P<object_no>\d+)/(?P<form_no>\d+)$', BaseView.as_view()),
```

views.py:

```
class BaseView(UpdateView):
    def get_object(self):     
        obj=MyModel.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['object_no'])  
        form_no = self.kwargs['form_no']
        if form_no=="1":
             self_fields=["field1","field2"...]
        .....
    def get_object(self):     
        obj=MyModel.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['object_no'])  
        form_no = self.kwargs['form_no']
        if form_no=="1":
             self_fields=["field1","field2"...]  
        .....             
        return obj
    def get_template_names(self):
        from_no = self.kwargs['form_no']
        if form_no=="1":
             return ["template1.html"]
        ....
```

You have to make sure that all your fields can be null.

Comment: This ended up being perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By defining `post` yourself, you've overridden the default behaviour of the view. You can see that there is no call to get_context_data, or any of the other class methods, so naturally they won't be called.

Generally you should not be overriding the specific get or post methods. You haven't shown the full view so it's not clear what behaviour you are trying to achieve, but for example in a form view you would want to define `success_url` to set the place the form redirects to after submission.